# auto sourcing vimrc breaks powerline

Tags: vim

I am running windows with gVim `version 7.3-46 (32bit)`

I have set up Vim to automatically source my .vimrc after saving it with

```
if has("autocmd")  
 autocmd bufwritepost vimrc.win source $MYVIMRC "Source config file on save  
endif
```

But when I issue the `:w` command my Powerline loses its color (it gets sourced indeed but breaks something). After reloading the file manually via `:source $MYVIMRC` the color returns. --> [MYVIMRC](https://github.com/tairun/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrc.win)

[image]

Comment: I can't tell you what causes that behaviour, but I'd just try to set the path to your ```.vimrc``` within the ```autocmd``` as a test to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I set the second argument to the absolut path, problem persists. I have a sym linked vimrc. But this shouldn't be a problem right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of [issue 213](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/issues/213#issuecomment-13510620). When resourcing vimrc always use autocmd-nested.

Comment: Thank, now it works perfectly. Otommod talks about another solution (https://github.com/fatih/subvim/pull/13#issuecomment-16436263) which doesn't work for me. Maybe it helps someone esle.   


TL:DR: add `au BufWritePost .vimrc PowerlineReloadColorscheme` to your config (not the solution ZyX talked about, go read his link)

Comment: @Sensei AFAIK this is the solution for deprecated vim-powerline. AFAIR it had the same bug when issuing `:colorscheme`, but I don’t remember whether or not it was fixed. In new powerline it fixes it by hooking `Colorscheme` event thus `nested` is required to make this event launch.

Comment: I'm still using `vim-powerline` instead of the new `powerline` though. Mainly because its "only" beta (never touch a running system ;-P)

Comment: @Sensei `vim-powerline` was a beta too. Now it is a deprecated beta.

Comment: Lokaltog is very smart, he disguised this with the greek letter so it wouldn't catch your eye immediately ;-D Just kidding. Never noticed it though.