# Reloading .vimrc in autocmd breaks Powerline

Tags: vim, color-scheme, vim-powerline

I know this has already been discussed, but the [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511778/auto-sourcing-vimrc-breaks-powerline) is not working for me.

I have this in my .vimrc:

```
autocmd! BufWritePost .vimrc nested source $MYVIMRC
```

Since I read that the correct way to source .vimrc inside an autocmd is using `autocmd-nested`.
Still, everytime I save it I lose colors in powerline

Edit:

here is my [.vimrc](http://pastebin.com/30mxsxLq)

```
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/vundle.git/
call vundle#rc()

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/bindings/vim

"set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
"set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
"set statusline+=%*
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=1

let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ra'
" Bundles
"
" original repos on github

"Bundle 'vim-scripts/taglist.vim'
Bundle 'majutsushi/tagbar'

"Bundle 'joonty/vim-phpqa.git'
"Bundle 'joonty/vim-phpunitqf'
Bundle 'joonty/vdebug'
" Php
Bundle 'sumpygump/php-documentor-vim'
Bundle 'sophacles/vim-processing'
Bundle 'nelstrom/vim-visual-star-search'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline'
Bundle 'spolu/dwm.vim'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-unimpaired'
Bundle 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Bundle 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Bundle 'wikitopian/hardmode'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'sbl/scvim'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/bufexplorer'
Bundle 'aaronbieber/quicktask'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/The-NERD-Commenter'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-surround'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/HTML-AutoCloseTag'
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
"Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/css_color.vim'
" Color schemes
Bundle 'tomasr/molokai'
Bundle 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Bundle 'vim-scripts/OOP-javascript-indentation'


let g:gitgutter_enabled = 0
set nocompatible "Don't be compatible with vi

" Enable filetype plugin
filetype indent on
filetype plugin on


" Set to auto read when a file is changed from the outside
set autoread

set t_Co=16
set background=dark                                            
set number "Show line numbering
set numberwidth=1 "Use 1 col + 1 space for numbers

" With a map leader it's possible to do extra key combinations
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","

" Toggle NERDTree
map <leader>n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

set backupdir=~/.vim/backup    " where to put backup files
set directory=~/.vim/temp    " where to put swap files

" Fast saving
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>

" Fast editing of the .vimrc
map <leader>e :e $MYVIMRC<cr>

" When .vimrc is edited, reload it
augroup MyAutoCmd
    autocmd!
augroup END

autocmd MyAutoCmd BufWritePost $MYVIMRC nested source $MYVIMRC
"au! BufWritePost .vimrc nested source %
set title

" Remap esc key
inoremap jk <esc>

" work more logically with wrapped lines
noremap j gj
noremap k gk

set smartcase " search case sensitive if caps on
set showcmd     " Display what command is waiting for an operator

autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead /*apache* setfiletype apache
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead /*lighttpd*.conf setfiletype lighty
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead {.,_}vimrc set foldmethod=marker

" PhpDocumentor
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.php inoremap <buffer> <leader>p :call PhpDoc()<CR>
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.php nnoremap <buffer> <leader>p :call PhpDoc()<CR>
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.php vnoremap <buffer> <leader>p :call PhpDocRange()<CR>


" Nicer highlighting of completion popup
highlight Pmenu guibg=brown gui=bold


set scrolloff=7 "Set 7 lines to the cursors when moving vertical
set wildmenu "Autocomplete features in the status bar
set ruler "Always show current position
set cmdheight=2 "The commandbar height
set hidden "Change buffer without saving

" Backspae config
set backspace=eol,start,indent
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l

set ignorecase "Search is case insensitive
set hlsearch "Highlight matches to the search
set incsearch "Show best match so far
set magic "Set magic on for regular expressions
set showmatch "Show matching bracets when text indicator is over them
set mat=2 "How many tenths of a second to blink

" No sound on errors
set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
set t_vb=

" Colors and fonts {{{1
set term=screen-256color
syntax enable "Enable syntax hl
syntax on "Enable syntax hl
"colorscheme molokai
"let g:solarized_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized
set guifont=Envy\ Code\ R\ for\ Powerline
set encoding=utf-8
filetype plugin on
"set guifont=Inconsolata\ for\ Powerline\
let g:Powerline_symbols="fancy"


" Text, tab and indent related {{{1

set expandtab "Transform tabs into spaces
set shiftwidth=4 "sw 4 spaces (used on auto indent)
set shiftwidth=4 "sw 4 spaces (used on auto indent)
set tabstop=4 "4 spaces as a tab for bs/del
set smarttab

set wrap linebreak tw=80 wm=0 "Wrap lines
set ai "Auto indent
set si "Smart indent
" }}}1
" Moving around, tabs and buffers {{{1

" Move to previous and next buffer
:nmap <C-n> :bnext<CR>
:nmap <C-p> :bprev<CR>

" Map space to / (search) and c-space to ? (backwards search)
map <space> /
map <c-space> ?
map <silent> <leader><cr> :noh<cr>

" Smart way to move between windows
map <C-j> <C-W>j
map <C-k> <C-W>k
map <C-h> <C-W>h
map <C-l> <C-W>l

" Mappings to access buffers (don't use "\p" because a
" delay before pressing "p" would accidentally paste).
" ,l       : list buffers
" ,b ,f ,g : go back/forward/last-used
" ,1 ,2 ,3 : go to buffer 1/2/3 etc
nnoremap <Leader>l :ls<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b :bp<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>f :bn<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>g :e#<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>1 :1b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>2 :2b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>3 :3b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>4 :4b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>5 :5b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>6 :6b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>7 :7b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>8 :8b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>9 :9b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>0 :10b<CR>

" Close the current buffer. Bclose defined below.
" dovrebbe già esistere in bufkill.vim
" map <leader>bd :Bclose<cr>

" Use the arrows to do something useful
map <right> :bn<cr>
map <left> :bp<cr>

" MiniBufExplorer settings
let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 1
let g:miniBufExplorerMoreThanOne = 2
let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 0
let g:miniBufExplUseSingleClick = 1
let g:miniBufExplMapWindowNavVim = 1

" Change directory to the file I'm editing
"autocmd BufEnter * lcd %:p:h
" When pressing <leader>cd switch to the directory of the open buffer
map <leader>cd :cd %:p:h<cr>

" Function to close buffer?
command! Bclose call <SID>BufcloseCloseIt()
function! <SID>BufcloseCloseIt()
   let l:currentBufNum = bufnr("%")
   let l:alternateBufNum = bufnr("#")

   if buflisted(l:alternateBufNum)
     buffer #
   else
     bnext
   endif

   if bufnr("%") == l:currentBufNum
     new
   endif

   if buflisted(l:currentBufNum)
     execute("bdelete! ".l:currentBufNum)
   endif
endfunction

" Specify the behavior when switching between buffers
try
    set switchbuf=usetab
    set stal=2
catch
endtry

nnoremap <C-e> 3<C-e>
nnoremap <C-y> 3<C-y>


" Always hide the statusline
set laststatus=2

" Format the statusline
set statusline=\ %F%m%r%h\ %w\ \ [%Y]\ \ CWD:\ %r%{CurDir()}%h\ \ \ Line:\ %l/%L:%c
"set statusline=%F%m%w\ Line:\ %l\/%L[%p%%]\ Col:\ %c\ Buf:\ #%n\ [%Y]\ [\%03.3b]\[\%02.2B]

function! CurDir()
    let curdir = substitute(getcwd(), '/Users/amir/', "~/", "g")
    return curdir
endfunction

" tab labels show the filename without path(tail)
set guitablabel=%N/\ %t\ %M

""" Windows
if exists(":tab")                                               " Try to move to other windows if changing buf
    set switchbuf=useopen,usetab
else                                                                    " Try other windows & tabs if available
    set switchbuf=useopen
endif

"""" Messages, Info, Status
set shortmess+=a                                                " Use [+] [RO] [w] for modified, read-only, modified
set report=0                                                    " Notify me whenever any lines have changed
set confirm                                                             " Y-N-C prompt if closing with unsaved changes

" we don't want to edit these type of files
set wildignore=*.o,*.obj,*.bak,*.exe,*.pyc,*.swp

"""" Coding
set history=1000                                                        " 1000 Lines of history
set showfulltag                                                 " Show more information while completing tags


" taglist plugin settings
"nnoremap <silent> <F8> :TlistToggle<CR>
let Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow = 1 "exit if taglist is last window open
let Tlist_Show_One_File = 1 "only show tags for current buffer
let Tlist_Enable_Fold_Column = 0  "no fold column (only showing one file)

" OmniCppComplete
let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 1
let OmniCpp_GlobalScopeSearch = 1
let OmniCpp_ShowAccess = 1
let OmniCpp_ShowPrototypeInAbbr = 1 " show function parameters
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot = 1 " autocomplete after .
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow = 1 " autocomplete after ->
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1 " autocomplete after ::
let OmniCpp_DefaultNamespaces = ["std", "_GLIBCXX_STD"]
" automatically open and close the popup menu / preview window
au CursorMovedI,InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|silent! pclose|endif
set completeopt=menuone,menu,longest,preview

let g:sparkupNextMapping = '<c-x>'

" SuperTab settings
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = '<c-x><c-o>'

""""" Folding
set foldmethod=syntax                                   " By default, use syntax to determine folds
set foldlevelstart=99                                   " All folds open by default



" Function to highlight character beyond column 79
" activate it with ,h
nnoremap <leader>h :call ToggleOverLengthHighlight()<CR>
let g:overlength_enabled = 0
" set the highlight color
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red guibg=red

function! ToggleOverLengthHighlight()
    if g:overlength_enabled == 0
        match OverLength /\%79v.*/
        let g:overlength_enabled = 1
        echo 'OverLength highlighting turned on'
    else
        match
        let g:overlength_enabled = 0
        echo 'OverLength highlighting turned off'
    endif
endfunction


" in visual mode press Ctrl r to start substituting text
vnoremap <C-r> "hy:%s/<C-r>h//gc<left><left><left>

" PHP Code Sniffer binary (default = "phpcs")
let g:phpqa_codesniffer_cmd='vendor/bin/phpcs'

" PHP Mess Detector binary (default = "phpmd")
let g:phpqa_messdetector_cmd='vendor/bin/phpmd'


set relativenumber

" important
" moving around, searching and patterns
" tags
" displaying text
" syntax, highlighting and spelling
" multiple windows
" multiple tab pages
" terminal
" using the mouse
" printing
" messages and info
" selecting text
" editing text
" tabs and indenting
" folding
" diff mode
" mapping

" toggle the tag list
nmap <Leader>tl :TlistToggle<CR>

" reading and writing files
" the swap file
" command line editing
" executing external commands
" running make and jumping to errors
" language specific
" multi-byte characters
" various



" TagList options

" set the names of flags
let tlist_php_settings = 'php;c:class;f:function;d:constant;p:property'
" close all folds except for current file
let Tlist_File_Fold_Auto_Close = 1
" make tlist pane active when opened
let Tlist_GainFocus_On_ToggleOpen = 1
" width of window
let Tlist_WinWidth = 60
" close tlist when a selection is made
let Tlist_Close_On_Select = 1
" show the prototype
let Tlist_Display_Prototype = 1
" show tags only for current buffer
let Tlist_Show_One_File = 1

" Taglist variables
" Display function name in status bar:
let g:ctags_statusline=1
" Automatically start script
let generate_tags=1
" Displays taglist results in a vertical windows:
let Tlist_Use_Horiz_Window=0
" Shorter commands to toggle Taglist display
nnoremap TT :TlistToggle<CR>
map <F4> :TlistToggle<CR>
" Various Taglist display config:
let Tlist_Use_Right_Windows = 1
let Tlist_Compact_Format = 1
let Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow = 1
let Tlist_GainFocus_On_ToggleOpen = 1
let Tlist_File_Fold_Auto_Close = 1

" Ctags options
nmap <Leader>tf :call CtagsFind(expand('<cword>'))<CR>
com! -nargs=+ Tf :call CtagsFind("<args>")
" split window and search for tag
nmap <Leader>ts :exe('stj '.expand('<cword>'))<CR>
set tags=tags;/

" open new tab and search for tag
"
fun! CtagsFind(keyword)
    tabe
    exe "tj ".a:keyword
endfunction

" TagBar
nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>

" CtrlP
let g:ctrlp_map = ',t'
nnoremap <silent> ,t :CtrlP<CR>
```

Comment: I guess you will have to show us your complete `.vimrc`.

Comment: I edited the question with a link to a pastebin with my .vimrc

Comment: I recommend copying the contents of your `.vimrc` into a code-block directly inside the question instead of providing us with a pastebin link, for better-ensured longevity.

Answer (score 1):

Your autocmd will be appended to your vim events.
You need handle reload with using augroup.

```
augroup MyAutoCmd
    autocmd!
    autocmd MyAutoCmd BufWritePost $MYVIMRC nested source $MYVIMRC
augroup END
```

Comment: Do you have any other MyAutoCmd?

Comment: Your variant is rather strange. Usually `autocmd BufWritePost` is put inside augroup, right after `autocmd!`. I prefer to use `augroup` and `autocmd! BufWritePost …` in place of `autocmd!`.

Comment: @Carlo That means that you should put everything into some autocmd group(s) and use `autocmd!`. This should not fix the issue, but not doing this means that each time you source vimrc one autocommand identical to already defined is added slowing down your vim and possibly introducing undesired side effects. Depending on what do your autocommands do you may not notice the slowness until, say, twentieth time, but this does not make your variant correct.

Comment: @ZyX When you say "everything into some autocmd group" you mean just this part related to autoloading `vimrc` or other stuff in the `vimrc`?
Anyway, I edited as you suggested, but still the same issue

Comment: @Carlo Every single autocommand. I did not say this will fix this issue. In fact, I did say “this should not fix the issue”. Just having issue with powerline does not prevent you from having another issues.

Comment: @ZyX Yes, thank you. I just wasn't sure, since I know almost nothing about Vim scripting. Now I read something about the augroup.